# syntax issue creating a method that returns an object (java)

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a method that will sum two timeO objects and return a new TimeO object called sum. 
Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
public static TimeO add (TimeO t1, TimeO t2) 
    {
        TimeO sum = new TimeO ;
```

...

```
    }
```

When I try to compile it I get this error message:

```
TimeO.java:15: '(' or '[' expected
                TimeO sum = new TimeO ;
                                      ^
1 error
```

I can't think of any reason why it would want me to open a set of parenthasies or brackets here but it's possible that I don't quite understand the syntax. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for calling a constructor is:

```
new TypeName(arguments)
```

So if you want to call a parameterless constructor, you should use:

```
TimeO sum = new TimeO();
```

Think of a constructor call (which is the way you create a new object) as being like a special kind of method call.